# mysql phpmyadmin replace string containing question mark

Tags: mysql, replace

replace old url by new url problem with question mark

I've tried to use folowing commands :

```
UPDATE `kiss_texte` SET `kt_txt` = replace(kt_txt, 'xxx://www.hotelpronto.com/?affiliateid=30606\', 'xxx://stohler.ch/promo/liste-promotion.php?local=fr');
```

> error:  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'xxx://stohler.ch/promo/liste-promotion.php?local=fr')' at line 1

or

```
UPDATE `kiss_texte` SET kt_txt = REPLACE(kt_txt, 'xxx://www.hotelpronto.com/?affiliateid=30606\', 'xxx://stohler.ch/promo/liste-promotion.php?local=fr') WHERE `kt_txt` LIKE 'http://www.hotelpronto.com/?aff ttttttttiliateid=30606\';
```

> error:  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'xxx://stohler.ch/promo/liste-promotion.php?local=fr') WHERE `kt_txt` LIKE 'http' at line 1

it seems that question mark is not interpreted as text

Comment: i had to replace http by xxx in this post as I don't have enough experience

Comment: Don't escape the quote.

Comment: can you explain "escape quote" ?

Comment: Get rid of the backslash in `\'`

Comment: you are right... my command get through.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Why are you escaping the single quotes `'` with preceding `\`?

```
UPDATE `kiss_texte` SET `kt_txt` = replace(kt_txt, 'xxx://www.hotelpronto.com/?affiliateid=30606', 'xxx://stohler.ch/promo/liste-promotion.php?local=fr');
```

If you still need the trailing backslash then you've to escape with double slash e.g `\\`

Comment: You should probably remove the backslash, not double it.